# Qt: how to set QDate (that is converted from QString) on QDateEdit field?

Tags: c++, qt, mainwindow, qdate

I have a QDateEdit field on my mainwindow.

I capture whatever date is selected by the user as QString before insert it into the database.

```
QString membership_Date = ui->memebershipDate->text();
```

Then, in case the user want to update the date, I retrieve the QString date from the database. Here is the last step in the process to retrieve the date as QString (and after checking, the whole process always return the correct date):

```
QString date_temp = modelToShow->record(row_index).value(11).toString();
```

Then I convert the QString to QDate as follow:

```
QDate membership_Date = QDate::fromString(date_temp,"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

However, when I try to set the QDateEdit field using the following:

```
ui->memebershipDate->setDate(membership_Date);
```

It doesn't work and the QDateEdit never change and shows the default date.

How to set this right?

Comment: Perhaps `QDate::fromString` fails, and debugging the value in membership_Date would shed some light on it?

Comment: What `membership_Date.isValid()` returns?

Comment: maybe debug it and find out the actual problem cus that looks fine, my guess is that date_temp isnt correct

Comment: @vahancho : the return value is false. But how to fix it, I mean what is the right syntax ?

Comment: @hauron : I am unable to debug , "locals & expressions" view is not operational. But, the return of `isValid` is false. I don't know any other syntax though

Comment: Why even use `QString`? The database probably supports date types, so they should be used instead of relying on a particular text format.

Comment: @AngryDuck: I am unable to debug , "locals & expressions" view is not operational. But, the return of `isValid` is false. I don't know any other syntax though and youself you said it looks fine. what might be the problem ?

Comment: i would say date temp string is incorrect, print the string to console and see what it is

Comment: @SergeyTachenov : You are right and I will change it eventually (it is a very tedious job, I have to change so many things and I want to do it carefully). For now though I want to work all the functionalities first (e.g.: update record details) and then later refine the code.

Comment: Well then, try printing `date_temp.toUtf8().toHex()` so we can see whether there are any bogus characters lurking about.

Comment: or simply print the date and make sure its actually a date

Comment: `std::cout << date_temp.toStdString() << std::endl;`

Comment: It is working now. I had to change `"dd/MM/yyyy"` to `"yyyy/MM/dd"` .. and that is it. Thanks for your help.